# Sprite kit rotation repeat

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

How do you make a sprite rock back and forth constantly like a boat?

Heres the code i wrote:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

let boat = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "boat_floor")
var rotationVal = CGFloat(-1)
class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    boat.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.width)
    boat.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: 0)
    boat.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "boat_floor"), size: boat.size)
    boat.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    boat.alpha = 1
    self.addChild(boat)
    ChangeAngle()
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector("ChangeAngle"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func ChangeAngle(){
    let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(rotationVal, duration:30)
    if rotationVal < 0 {
        rotationVal = CGFloat(M_PI)
        boat.runAction(action)
    }
    else if rotationVal > 0 {
        rotationVal = -CGFloat(M_PI)
        boat.runAction(action)
    }
    print(rotationVal)


}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do it like this (just copy&paste the code to see how it works):

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

let boat = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.greenColor(), size:CGSize(width: 200, height: 80))


class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        boat.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: 100)

        boat.alpha = 1
        self.addChild(boat)


        let rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(-0.6, duration:4)

        let sequence = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([rotate, rotate.reversedAction()]))

        let complete = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.rotateByAngle(0.3, duration:2), sequence])

        boat.runAction(complete, withKey:"someKey")

    }

}
```

Using NSTimer is generally bad idea in SpriteKit because it don't respect node's, scene's or view's paused state.